# Unit Testing for Windows Registry Operations

Tags: c#

I want to Mock windows registry which I need to use in my unit testing Using C#.
I have written function to set registry for HKLM and HKCU.How to do I write Unit testing for the below function. I don't want to use systemWrapper
Please could any one help on this

```
  public static bool createHkcuRegistry(string registryPath, string valueName, string value, RegistryValueKind valueKind = RegistryValueKind.String)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(registryPath, true);
            if (key != null)
            {
                key.SetValue(valueName, value, valueKind);
                key.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                RegistryKey newKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(registryPath);
                newKey.SetValue(valueName, value, valueKind);
            }
            return true;
        }        
      }
```

Comment: Why don't you want with `systemWrapper`?

Comment: Since you don't want to use SystemWrapper then you can recreate the abstraction yourself as the best path to solving this requirement is via abstracting registry access

Comment: I need to impersonate the actual registry, how do i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to truly mock, inject dependency of it to any consumer through interface. Something like:

```
public interface IRegistryService
{
  bool CreateHkcuRegistry(string registryPath, string valueName, string value, RegistryValueKind valueKind = RegistryValueKind.String);
}

public class RegistryService : IRegistryService
{
  public bool CreateHkcuRegistry(string registryPath, string valueName, string value, RegistryValueKind valueKind = RegistryValueKind.String)
  {
    try
    {
      RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(registryPath, true);
      if (key != null)
      {
         key.SetValue(valueName, value, valueKind);
         key.Close();
      }
      else
      {
         RegistryKey newKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(registryPath);
                    newKey.SetValue(valueName, value, valueKind);
      }
      return true;
    }        
  }
}
```

Sample of usage:

```
public class ConsumerSample
{
   privare IRegistryService _registryService;

   public ConsumerSample(IRegistryService registryService)
   {
      _registryService = registryService;
   }

   public void DoStuffAndUseRegistry()
   {
       // stuff
       // now let's save
       _registryService.CreateHkcuRegistry("test","testValue","mytest");
   } 
}


var consumer = new ConsumerSample(new RegistryService());
```

Then use real implementation where desired and mock it in tests where needed.

Comment: While unit testing the above function, it should not touch the system Registry... So I need to Mock the system registry

Comment: @VJL then you need to create a mock of the `IRegistryService` and use that. Mocking the system registry is way to broad to do on your own. Abstract the functionality you want and then mock that.

Comment: Then there is no use of unit testing if I mock IRegistryService

Comment: @VJL, your responses are confusing. We may be misunderstanding each other. You say it should not touch system registry. that is correct. that is why we mock up a service that impersonates the actual registry for the unit test. If you actually touch system registry then it is no longer a unit test, but changes to an integration test. You would like to unit test your function without actually touching system registry. then mock the functionality you want. That is what I am trying to explain and what the above answer tried to explain as well. Do we understand each other no or am I mistaken?

Comment: I need to impersonate the actual registry. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same challenge in an open source library I maintain. There's a full implementation of the registry which supports mocking and testing I put together here:

https://github.com/dwmkerr/dotnet-windows-registry

The usage would be just as described in Vidas' answer.